# Docker MariaDb - remote access

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I'm trying to set up remote access to MariaDb via Traefik:

MariaDB docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"

services:
  jpz-mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=database
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass
    networks:
      - web
    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - jpz-mariadb:/var/lib/mysql:nocopy # I want to manage volumes manually.
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=jpz-mariadb'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:mariadb.localtest.me'

  jpz-pma:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: jpz-mariadb
      PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE: 1G
      PHP_MAX_INPUT_VARS: 1G
    networks:
      - web
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=jpz-pma'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:pma.localtest.me'

volumes:
  jpz-mariadb:
    external: true

networks:
  web:
    external:
      name: traefik_webgateway
```

And Traefik docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  proxy:
    image: traefik
    command: --web --docker --docker.domain=localtest.me --logLevel=DEBUG
    networks:
      - webgateway
    ports:
      - "81:80"
      - "3307:3306"
      - "443:443"
      - "8081:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /dev/null:/traefik.toml

networks:
  webgateway:
    driver: bridge
```

I'm not able to connect to mariadb.localtest.me:3307 via `mysql -u root -p -h mariadb.localtest.me -P 3307`

Getting:

> Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0 (Mysql2::Error)

How to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get any further with this? I've been trying to set up something similar with a MySQL container. Even when I open up the ports to the web and treat everything as if it's a normal web connection, the database container stays unconnectable.

Comment: no I didn't but I think Traefik can redirect only HTTP/HTTPS access, so you need to expose that port without traefik proxy..

Comment: Yeah, that sounds about right. I didn't realize at first that Traefik was restricted to HTTP(S) only -- I actually thought it could handle any TCP traffic.